# Laravel User activity DB Logger

Tags: php, mysql, logging, laravel, laravel-4

Hey Guys I have researched and have tested few method for logging user activity such as when an user updates his profile details or when an user updates his status in a task.

**What I require to log :**

- User ID from session
- Table being updated
- Field Name
- Old Value
- New Value
- Timestamps

**Method 1:** 
Run an additional query along with the insert/update/delete query to store details.

**Method 2:** 
Using http://packalyst.com/packages/package/regulus/activity-log

In both the above methods I have to write multiple code for each create/update/delete I would like to know if there exist a better way to handel this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few days ago I've created such package, which, unlike VentureCraft's one, logs only static data - tables, values. No fks, no model names etc.

Also it handles the revisions in different manner, which makes it **much easier to eg. compare given 2 versions**, since it doesn't log single field change per row, but all the data involved per row.

#### Check this out: [Sofa/Revisionable](https://packagist.org/packages/sofa/revisionable)

This is pretty young and will be improved.

It's also not `Eloquent` specific, but it **works out of the box with Laravel 4**. You simply download it, adjust config if needed, add a few lines of code to your models and it's ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

You want to store revisions of the data being manipulated by the user.

This calls for [Revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable).

Revisionable works using trait-implementation. Every action made by the user, will have the old and new value of the column stored in a seperate table. You can then query the revisionable table to get the changes made by the user.

Please note that the Revisionable version quoted above, doesn't store INSERT actions.